# How can I set Mac OS X Lion to use browser GMail as a default mail app?

Tags: osx-lion, gmail

I have set up Chrome (my primary browser) to use gmail when I click an email link.  However, when I right-click a file on the desktop and select "New Email with Attachment" OS X launches Mail.app.  Is there a way to make it open a gmail compose window tab in my browser instead?

Answer (score 1):

The New Email with Attachment service is a feature of Mail. It is built into Mail, and Mail provides it as a service to other applications.

I wonder if you could use [this](http://www.officeformachelp.com/2010/11/create-a-service-to-attach-files-to-a-new-outlook-for-mac-mail-message/) but modify it to point to the code written below (the method you are using to make this work in Chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

There are different instructions for different browsers [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/09/gmail-default-email-client-for-chrome-firefox-safari/).

As an example, this is for Chrome and Opera:

- Launch a new browser window and open up Gmail
- Open the Javascript console by hitting Command+Option+J and then paste in the following:

> navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto",
>   "https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s", "Gmail");

and a bit of clarification from further down the page...

> *After entering CMD+OPT+J, notice to the right of the “x” where you can close out, a series of choices: “Elements, Resources,
>   Network…etc…Console”. Click the “Console” and paste the code to the
>   right of the “>” symbol and then close out. Then, as the above
>   directions show, Gmail will then prompt to accept the confirmation at
>   the top of the browser window.

Accept the confirmation at the top of the browser window and try out a mailto link

Check out the link though if you're using a different browser.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Josh.  However, this solution only accomplishes what I state in the question above that I am already able to do (use gmail to open email links when I click them in Chrome).  I am specifically seeking a way to launch GMail when I use 'mail links' from OUTSIDE THE BROWSER itself, i.e. with the "New Email with Attachment" option from the context menu when right-clicking a file on the OS X Desktop.

Comment: Ah, you're right of course.  :)